# How to create hashed password which could be used for many Linux Servers?

Tags: linux, hash

I have tried to generate online hash for my password, to store it in secure looking way and then with ansible to apply it as a new root password for the servers. However, it does not quite work, it works for a few VMs but for all other Linux servers it fails to login with it (I'm trying to login with my unhashed password)

Getting login into the many servers with unhashed password, where I have placed beforehand my hashed password

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.